# Adding documents to Lucene Index Writer after commit is called

Tags: java, lucene, commit, indexwriter

I am using Lucene 4.6. I created a Lucene IndexWriter(in CREATE MODE) and added documents and committed it(didnt close it). Then ran a search query and stored the results. Again I added documents to the index writer and committed it and closed it. And ran a search query on it. It gave results with new data and old data also. The old data was also present in the index. May i know the way to delete all the data from the index. Is there any way to delete all the documents at a stretch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexwriter.deleteall method will delete all the documents in the index and you can reuse the same indexwriter to build INDEX on new documents and run a search query and close it later when you need

Answer (score 1):

That would be better if you could provide us the code snippet, but it seems the issue is you are using `OpenMode.CREATE` instead of `OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND`. In that case, each time you create the `IndexWriter` object, the old data is overritten, not appended.

Also, make sure you are using the latest version. The current is v4.9.0

Comment: Thanks @serem. Actually i am new to lucene and so i didnt understand the basic functality. I found out that there is a deleteall function which can be used to remove all the previously indexed documents.